# How to load iframe only once when place it in 2 places in React

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I have a page written in React:

```
const Page = () => {
  const iframeRef = useRef(null);

  const iframe = <iframe src="/some-url" ref={iframeRef} />;

  // place iframe in 2 places
  return (
    <div>
      {iframe}
      ...some other content
      {iframe}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What it does is just to load iframe and put it in 2 places in the same page.

With the current implementation, the page treats it as 2 different iframes. Both hitting url `/some-url`, which really slows down the whole loading process and causes burden on the server.

I want to optimize this by just loading iframe once. Just one iframe hitting that url and once it's done, create a copy of it and put it in the 2nd spot.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: **I am not sure** but the reason the iframes load as different iframes, because they are different iframes. And React is not the reason for that but HTML is. Maybe you can defer the loading of iframes? Maybe load them in didMount?

Comment: there's no such thing in React which allow you to use one instance and put in two different places. These two `iframe` has to be physically two instances, although they could be derived from the same component. However if i load the web page content once, can i display the result in two different places? yes, you can. So you need to display the html as the API content.

Answer (score 1):

method might not be suitable for all scenarios. If the content inside the iframe changes, method might not work as well.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [iframeLoaded, setIframeLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* component that does the actual loading */}
      {iframeLoaded || <IFrame onLoad={() => setIframeLoaded(true)} />}
      
      
      {iframeLoaded && <IFramePlaceholder />}
      {iframeLoaded && <IFramePlaceholder />}
    </div>
  );
};

const IFrame = ({ onLoad }) => (
  <iframe 
    src="https://example.com" 
    style={{ display: 'none' }} 
    onLoad={onLoad}
  ></iframe>
);

const IFramePlaceholder = () => (
  <div>
    {/*to display the iframe content. 
          */}
  </div>
);

export default ParentComponent;
```

My suggestion: If you're trying to avoid loading some heavy page content multiple times, consider alternatives to iframes, such as loading it via AJAX and displaying it directly in your React

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is when the the server where the iframe comes from adds Cache-Control header.

If you don't own this server, you can try to "hijack" this endpoint and server this exact content with those headers.

In Nodejs, Express, this would look something like this:

```js
const exampleUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/qBj02LwojNo'
const axiosConfig = {
    method: 'get',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    headers: {
        Cookie:
            "CONSENT=PENDING+797; VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=BwuEebbS6oU; YSC=KVz7BYbs6So"
    }
};
router.route('/')
    .get((req,res) => {
        try {
            const response = axios.get({ ...axiosConfig, url: exampleUrl }).then((response) => response?.data);

            // Set Cache-Control headers for caching
            res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=60'); // Cache for 60 seconds

            // Serve the fetched content as the response
            res.send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching content:', error.message);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred while fetching content.');
        }
    });
```